# Why a 1x1 GIF instead of XHR?

Tags: ajax, google-analytics, xmlhttprequest, web-analytics

Simple question: why do client-side scripts (like `ga.js` from Google Analytics) send data to the server in the form of query params embedded in a 1x1 GIF request? Why not use XMLHttpRequest?

Is it just to achieve cross-browser compatibility? Or are there other reasons?

Comment: it works and it much less complicated than XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "less complicated"? XHR is a more direct means for what the developer is trying to achieve. The GIF method is essentially a hack.

Comment: All they're trying to achieve is make a request.  Browsers have been able to make requests for images when the pages loads forever.  What more do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xhr is subject to same origin policy and not all clients have reliable scripting support. gif beacons are solid as a solution.
//should be a comment

Comment: Yes, right answer. AJAX is for same-origin requests (except with CORS, which doesn't have universal support).